# Determine the probability of numeric typing error

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, numeric

I have:

1. Correct numerical ID such as Phone number / Social-security number / etc.
2. Another number, from some data-entry form

The 2nd number is similar, but not equal to the 1st number.
Both numbers are valid.

I want to calculate how probable it is that the 2nd number is actually a typing error of the 1st number.

Such errors may include:

- Off by a few digits
- Transposed digits
- Misinterpreted digits (1-7, 4-9, 3-8, 2-5)

Does anyone know about existance of such algorithm / code?

**Edit:**

I'm not looking for a general string-similarity algorithm. I'm looking for an algorithm optimized for human number-entry typing errors, or for some research about this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several [algorithms to measure a string similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aString_similarity_measures).

You could implement some variant of the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) or Damerau-Levenshtein distance that rates the types of errors differently.

Answer (score 0):

Treat the numbers as a sequence of digits and Calculate the similarity ratio between the two numbers.

`2.0*M / T.`
 
Where T is the number of digits in both numbers 
M is the number of matches in the 2 numbers

a similarity ratio of 0.6 and above means the 2 numbers  are similar

Note that the ratio is 1 if the numbers are identical, and 0 if
they have no digit  in common.